# Identifying a hash function knowing both input and output

Tags: hash-functions

I am creating a custom client for an old game. Now I got stuck on login to the server. I made several experiments with wireshark but it doesn't seem to be any common hashes.
From my limited understanding, it doesn't seem to be salted because the same input gets the same output even if I change my account, device, ip...
Here are some inputs and outputs:

00000 - 5a5ef2

000000 - 9a5af4

0000000 - daacf7

11111 - 763443

01010 - 0660bf

22222 - 82eff1

123123123123 - 368188

password - 8606df

☺☺☺☺☺ - e27952